# What do exceptions allow us to separate?

Tags: c++, exception

I would like to know what do exceptions allow us to separate? It would be nice if you can explain with an appropriate example using c++

Comment: They separate control-flow from error-flow

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thats what i am asking. Its a question that was asked to me. An i am unbale to answer it

Comment: @eznme Thanks for the answer now i understand what the question meant. Is it possible to give a short example.

Comment: @user1835958: You should ask for a clarification as the question is not clear. You should ask for some context.

Comment: @eznme: To _some_ degree. But not a lot, since they both delimit scope blocks

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions make your code cleaner do you don't need to clutter your code with `if` statements, just wrap it with `try..catch`. So they separate your code from error checking.

The intention is good, but exceptions also carry some problems, like forgetting to wrap the code with try..catch. Java protects against that using a compiler error.

I use exceptions mainly in function where I need to perform many actions, each one depends on the success of the preceeding action. So I make all the action throw an exception. I also name them such that they reflect the fact that they throw an exception.

Comment: _forgetting to wrap the code with try..catch. Java protects against that using a compiler error._ - in C++ this is an anti-pattern to avoid. The idiomatic C++ way is to use destructors for clean-up, so that `try/catch` are rarely necessary. Obviously, Java lacks destructors which leads to heavy use of `try/catch`, which somewhat defeats the purpose of exceptions to separate program flow code from error handling code.